# Null pointer dereference in netbeans meaning

Tags: java, pointers, netbeans, null, dereference

Netbeans reports null pointer dereference in this method in my code. I'm not a code wizard and 
i need to find out what that means, how it affect the running code and possible errors it can cause.

```
    public ArrayList<String> getKompetensdomanerBeskrivning(){
    ArrayList<String> kompetensdomanerBeskrivning = null;
    for(Kompetensdoman kompdoman : kompetensdomaner){
        kompetensdomanerBeskrivning.add(kompdoman.getBeskrivning());
    }
    return kompetensdomanerBeskrivning;
}
```

Comment: so initialize `kompetensdomanerBeskrivning`...

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, edited.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ right, I just read the two first lines by mistake... Got it right after I've wrote it.

Comment: @matan7890 No problem :). It happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<String> kompetensdomanerBeskrivning = null;
```

You are initialized it to `null`. That is the reason for the warn. With present code, if you run the code, you run into `NullPointerException`.

Change that to

```
   ArrayList<String> kompetensdomanerBeskrivning = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or

```
      ArrayList<String> kompetensdomanerBeskrivning = null;

               //some code here

      ArrayList<String> kompetensdomanerBeskrivning =  new ArrayList<String>();//no warn
```

It means then and then, when you are going to use that instance which is pointing to still null, you'll see that warning.

Comment: So when an object is initialised to null it reports that every time?

Comment: @XenoLyse No, when object is null it means it is not initialized. 
When object is not initialized it means you can't reference to it, because it doesn't really "exists".

Comment: @XenoLyse  No. Initially you may initiaze it to null, but later you may reinitialize it with actual Class.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Just for accuracy, when you initialize an object to null, it means that only it's reference is initialized, but not the object itself. So it is not really "reinitialize".